# How to fix crashes Visual Studio 2013 SSIS crash at design time

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis, oledb, sql-server-data-tools, dts

I am setting up an SSIS solution to move data from several flat and excel sources and load them, after some transformation into several MS Access files. 
As I set up the destination (being it OLEDB, ODBC, or even excel as destination), the moment I click on the name of table or view drop down VS crashes and gives me the following report:

I have installed on a Windows 10 64 bit with Office 2016 (32 bit)
the following:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Version 12.0.21005.1 REL
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01586
- NuGet Package Manager   2.7.40911.287
- SQL Server Analysis Services
- Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services Designer Version 12.0.2000.8
- SQL Server Data Tools   12.0.30919.1
- Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
- SQL Server Integration Services
- Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer Version 12.0.2430.0
- SQL Server Reporting Services
- Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers Version 12.0.2430.0

I have tried:

- Different connections types (OLEDB, OCDB, Excel)
- Different files, both local and on network
- Tried to switch on and off validation of external metadata
- Tried different access modes (SQL, table/view)

VS crashes and I get the following message from the debugger.

> System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Apologies if I provided some irrelevant info, just have no idea what is the cause.

Comment: I had your VS + SSDT/SSSIS/SSRS and was making SSIS packages fine on a windows 7 box. I'd try patching the VS install. That's the [RTM build](https://omwtm.blog/2014/12/03/visual-studio-2013-version-numbers-and-updates/) -  get Update 5. Tools, Extensions and Updates -> Updates

Comment: Thanks billinkc for the feedback. I tried to use a more recent version, but VS2015 (v.14.0.23107) with SS Data Tool 14.0.61712.050 has the exact same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Is this info of any use regarding the same exception in System.Windows.Forms.dll? It could be due to a corrupt .NET installation.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/84daaa92-88cc-4524-a2d8-ed7e9132bd07/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-systemaccessviolationexception-occurred-in

Comment: Thanks tim, I tried in two different computers from my collogues and it fails in the exact same way so I don't think it is the .net. I will post back if I ever solve this. I suspect it has to do with something related to accesses or virus protection.

Answer (score 0):

The issues seem to have "solved itself" as I did several Windows 10 updates that included .Net updates.
I suspect, (but can't be certain) that the actual cause may have been linked to an outdated .Net framework that caused the issue. 
I have moved to .Net 4.8

Hope this helps anyone with similar issues